# python3 why root_a return None value in my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is like this and the input is here.

5 6

1 2

1 5

2 4

3 4

3 5

4 5

when i put  2 4 , the value root_a is None. but i don't understand why root_a return None . i tried to debug on pycharm but i don't know why...
Does anyone can help?

```
node, edge = list(map(int, input().split()))
root_list = [x for x in range(node)]


def find_root(x):
    print(x, 'x')
    if x == root_list[x]:
        return x
    root_x = find_root(root_list[x])
    root_list[x] = root_x


for _ in range(edge):
    a, b = list(map(int, input().split()))
    a = a - 1
    b = b - 1
    root_a = find_root(a)
    root_b = find_root(b)
    print(root_a, root_b, 'root')
    if root_a != root_b:
        root_list[b] = root_a
    print(root_list)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't return the found value in `find_root`.
If you return no value 'None' is returned.

In the third iteration of your loop `_ == 2` you call `find_root(1)` which then calls `find_root(0)` but that value isn't returned after being assigned to `root_x`. Instead `None` is returned implicitly and `root_a` becomes `None`. As `None != 3` you assign `None` into your `root_list` in line 21.

I'm unsure what you program wants to do but try this:

```
def find_root(x):
    print(x, 'x')
    if x == root_list[x]:
        return x
    root_x = find_root(root_list[x])
    root_list[x] = root_x
    return root_x # add this line
```

Answer (score 1):

I apologize if I understand your code wrongly. I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve ;(

But I can tell you why it's `None` when you input `2 4`

that is because in the function `find_root` you are returning nothing if `x != root_list[x]`

see below for `find_root` function with comments

```
def find_root(x):
    print(x, 'x')
    if x == root_list[x]:
        return x
    # here if x != root_list[x], the code will continue
    # but there is no return, hence it's treated as if it returns None
    root_x = find_root(root_list[x])
    root_list[x] = root_x
    # you might need a return here?
    return root_x
```